# PHP - Conexión FTP: ftp_put(): Server cannot accept argument

Tags: php

¿Qué tal? Paso a consultar un problemilla que traigo de unos días,

Al tratar de enviar un archivo temporal creado en un PHP por medio de FTP, me sale un error el cual, únicamente me muestra al ejecutarlo en el servidor del hosting, lo he probado de manera local con Xampp y no me da esté problema, quizás deba configurar algo en CPanel (Abrí puertos 20 y 21 TCP/UDP), no lo sé y pido si me pueden orientar un poco, gracias!

ERROR: PHP Warning:  ftp_put(): Server cannot accept argument. in /home/... on line 9

```html
<?php
//Creamos un achivo temporal
$arch = tmpfile();

//Guardamos el archivo XML manipulado
fwrite($arch, $Base_xml->saveXML());

//Cargar el archivo en FTP con la ruta temporal
if (ftp_put($cid, "archivo.xml", stream_get_meta_data($arch)['uri'], FTP_ASCII)) {
  //Se realizó el envió con éxito
  //Eliminamos el archivo temporal, liberamos conexión de FTP
  fclose($arch);
  ftp_close($cid);
  return 1;
}
?>
```

De antemano muchas gracias! _o/

Comment: Te hace falta conectar el FTP con ftp_connect.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero la conexión no está en cuestión, dado que si logra hacer inicio de sesión por decirlo. El tema es que al hacer el put da el error mencionado en el post.